# How can I prevent hover styles when element is focused

Tags: html, css, hover, focus

I've created an  element, and when you hover over it, the border color changes from the original. There is also another color that the border changes to when the border is focused.
HTML:

```
<input id="colorchange" type="text">
```

CSS:

```
#colorchange {border: thin solid white;}
#colorchange:hover {border: thin solid grey;}
#colorchange:focus {border: thin solid black;}
```

The problem is that I want the border to stay black when the element is focused, even if the user is hovering over it. Unfortunately, when I hover over the element when it is focused, the element becomes gray, though I want it to stay black.
How can I do this?

Comment: if any of the answers addressed your question, make sure you select one as the correct one (big check mark below the voting buttons); vote it up too if you feel like it...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do the styling is give one class higher priority over another. Avoid using `!important` as it creates issues creating rule priorities.

Using simple class names instead of ID you could do:

```
.colorchange:hover {border: thin solid grey;}
.colorchange.colorchange:focus {border: thin solid black;}
```

The double class name declaration is allowed and give the second class higher priority.

Another way of setting priorities is assigning specificity. One rule being more specific than the other:

```
#colorchange:hover {border: thin solid grey;}
body #colorchange:focus {border: thin solid black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the same setting for the hover of the element in your css by adding them on the same line, separated by comma:

```css
/* These two element selectors are now on the same line, separated by comma */
#colorchange, #colorchange:hover { border: thin solid white; }

#colorchange:focus { border: thin solid black; }
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B29VK/)**

Answer (score 0):

try

`#colorchange input[type='text']:focus{border: thin solid black;}`

Comment: think the OP meant to keep the same border color in case of hover... your above code is merely rewriting the same code the OP already has...

Answer (score 0):

set !important property on hover style

```
#colorchange {border: thin solid white;}
#colorchange:hover {border: thin solid grey !important;}
#colorchange:focus {border: thin solid black;}
```